# Akka-Http per server instance configuration

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-http

I have multiple `akka-http` server instances running on different ports as part of the same jvm process. The server instances have different performance requirements and need to be configured differently.

Is it possible to configured them on a per-instance basis.

I Could find nothing in the official docs, nor anywhere else.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html

Comment: How are you starting the Akka HTTP servers? I would guess there's a way to specify a specific config file instead of the default one when starting it.

Comment: Out of curiosity though, what's the use case of such a setup?

Comment: There is the main server and a separate server for performance metrics, one for health checks and so on. I know that these routes could be moved a single server, but due to historical reasons this is not easily achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerBuilder` returned by `Http#newServerAt` can be configured with different `ServerSettings` using `withSettings` or `adaptSettings`, either modifying programatically or loading a whole new block from config using `ServerSettings#apply(Config)` and separate materializers (that can have further separate settings for default dispatcher etc) using `withMaterializer`.